# Energy degeneracy given a rigid-rotor Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, hamiltonian

I'm trying to work out the degeneracy of some energy levels in a Hamiltonian given by

$H = \frac{1}{2a} (L_x^2 + L_y^2) + \frac{1}{2b} L_z^2$.

Looking for a common base of eigenstates $Y_l^m$ trying to have $H$ as a function of $L^2$ and $L_z$ I arrive to the conclussion that the energy levels of the system are given  by

$E_{l, m} = \frac{\hbar^2}{2a} l(l+1) + \hbar^2 m^2 \left( \frac{1}{2b} - \frac{1}{2a} \right)$.

How could I study the degeneracy of those energy levels? Should the value of the real constants $a, b$ be known? I'm trying to solve it taking into acount that $|m|\leq l$ but I can't work it out.

Could you give me some hints? Thank you very much

Comment: Hint: What are the values $l$ and $m$ can take?

Comment: Hi, @SuperfastJellyfish, thanks for your comment. I know $|m| \leq l$, so, given a value of $n$, we have $l = 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1$ and given each of those values of $l$, we have $m = -l, ..., 0, ..., l$. But is there any posibility that I can obtain the same value of $E$ given 2 different values of $l$ because of the liberty I have with $m$? Should I know the values of $a$ and $b$ in order to answer that wuestion? If a = b, then it's clear (I think) that the energy levels are not degenerate, but what about $a \neq b$?

Comment: If $a=b$, the hamiltonian is proportional to $L^2$ so there is a $2l+1$ degeneracy in that case. For the other case there is a straightforward 2-fold degeneracy for $m,-m$. Now coming to your question, you can solve for two $m$s taking two different $l$s and see what condition you get on the $m$s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Degeneracy* occurs when the same value of energy occurs for *different* quantum numbers.  Thus here you must ask: is there more than one choice of $\ell$ and $m$ that will produce the same energy?  There are (broadly) two kinds of degeneracies: essential and accidental.

Clearly in your proposed expression (if it is correct) $\pm m$ will have the same energy, so your energy levels are at least 2-fold degenerate, except for $m=0$.

Assuming $a\ne b$, your Hamiltonian is that of a rigid rotor or rigid top, 
Now pick a value of $\ell$ and make a table of possible energies systematically using different $m$’s. This should provide you insight into what other possible degeneracies there might be.
Note that if you assume $a=b$, you have a spherical top and the situation will be quite different: all allowed $m$’s will be degenerate.

The above are examples of essential degeneracies: they will occur for any values of $a,b$ and depend only on the quantum numbers $\ell$ and $m$.

Next, you may also want to investigate the possible appearance of *accidental* degeneracies.  That would happen because the coefficients $a$ and $b$ happen *by accident* to be such that more than one combination of $\ell(\ell+1)$ and $m^2$ give you the same energies.  The accidental degeneracies are less obvious to identify and you will need to do a bit of experimenting with the ratio of $a$ and $b$ to see if this can happen with your Hamiltonian.  If you rewrite
\begin{align}
E_{l, m} &= \frac{\hbar^2}{2a} l(l+1) + \hbar^2 m^2 \left( \frac{1}{2b} - \frac{1}{2a} \right)\, ,\\
&=\frac{\hbar^2}{2a}\left[l(l+1)+ m^2\left(r-1 \right)\right] \tag{1}
\end{align}
for some ratio of $r=a/b$, can you find different $m_1\ne m_2$, $l_1\ne l_2$ so that 
\begin{align}
\frac{l_1(l_1+1)+m_1^2(r-1)}{l_2(l_2+1)+m_2^2(r-1)}=1? \tag{2}
\end{align}

Comment: and one must not forget that $|m_i|\le l_i$

Comment: Thank you! In the case of $a \neq b$ I get that for $m$ = 0 the degeneracy is obvously 1 and for $m \neq 0$ the degeneracy is always 2. I'll think about the last thing you commented.

Comment: yes... those are essential degeneracies.  Accidental ones are harder to find, i.e. can you find $r,l_1,l_2,m_1,m_2$ so that (2) holds?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Thank you!!! I tried with Mathematica and I found a lot of sets of numbers which follow that equation, i.e. $r = \frac{17}{6}, l_1 = 4, m_1 = \pm 4, l_2 = 6, m_2 = \pm 2$. I should take them into account when studying the degeneracy of the energy levels!